# Does completing a difficulty level provide any advantage in later playthroughs?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

I passed DMC on Devil Hunter. Should I repeat the game on Easy to get all the doors and souls before going onto Son of Sparda or is it irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's irrelevant as far as fighting goes other than the fact that you get to play through with all your upgrades. But as far as all the doors and souls, yes and no.

For the doors, once you enter them, all the doors have a default difficulty. So no matter what mode your playing in, Son of Sparda, Dante Must Die, etc., the demons in the doors remain the same. Really weak after you've upgraded.

As far as souls, you do technically require certain weapons and upgrades to even reach some of the souls.